# Cannot get php file to run in browser? Ubuntu

Tags: apache-http-server, php

I am trying to run a .php file that reads information from a MySQL database. I have installed php5:

```
developer@alchemy:~/dev$ php --version
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.13 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul  7 2014 18:52:09) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

I have apache2 installed and running:

```
developer@alchemy:~/dev$ sudo netstat -ntlup
[sudo] password for developer: 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN        1224/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      30018/apache2
```

Here is the Display.php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Display udp packet</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background-color: #29C;
}
.display-box {
  border: solid 2px #FFF;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$dbcnx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", '', "udp");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
<div align="center">
<p class="display-box">Data:
<?php
  #Select Database
  mysql_select_db("data")

  #Collect data from table "data"
  $result = mysqli_query($dbcnx, "SELECT * FROM data");

  #temporary test display
  echo "<p>$data</p>";

 # while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {    
 #   echo $row['packetdata'] . " " . $row['date'];
 # }

  #mysql_close($dbcnx);
?>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The file is found in the pathway /home/developer/dev/Display.php
The method I found online to display the php file was to type into the search bar:

`http://localhost/where/file/is/saved/Display.php`

This however, returns a

"Not Found

The requested URL /display.php was not found on this server." Message. How do I run the php file? Have I missed something out?

Comment: To start with, the file name you have requested (in browser) is not the same as what you're actually after... `Diplayer.php` vs `Display.php`

Comment: Oops, that was a typo in the question, thank you for pointing out, but the question still stands :)

Comment: Have you checked the permission of your file? Apache required a specific user or chmod to display your file (don't use root). Also, check if Apache have your path as default web folder.

Comment: The file permission are as follows:
```-rw-rw-r-- 1 developer developer 903 Aug 12 15:19 display.php
```
My understanding of this is that the "developer" user had permission to read and write that file. I installed apache2 using this account, but I don't understand the part of your comment about apache requiring a user to display file. How can I check that?

Comment: http://localhost goes to the www directory (probably /var/www), not to /home/... Try this: make a symlink in de /var/www directory and make sure every directory below /home/developer/dev is readable by the apache deamon (ln -s /var/www/dev /home/developer/dev/).